# How to enable only HOUR when using Material Time Picker?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am unable to disable the MINUTE picker, meaning I want to enable only HOUR picker but no luck.
Material Time Picker allows to set min and max time, hour and minute. Yet, for some reasons, I wonder if we can enable only the HOUR picker.

UPDATE: I'm using this library:
https://agranom.github.io/ngx-material-timepicker/

Comment: what did you try post some code please

Comment: Why not to use drop down with 24 options?

Comment: what do you mean Material Time Picker? There is no material time picker. Do you mean some other third party app?

Answer (score 0):

If you ask is it possible to pick only hours, it is not possible in angular material datepicker even there is no timer picker. If you want only time picker you need to use third party app. It's currently an open issue on angular material github page, [github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5648)